# Flutter - New StatefullWidget, why related createState() method not called?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

in the 'TestPageState', I put a button to call 'setState' method. new TestChildWidget() will create a new  TestChildWidget,default construtor TestChildWidget() is called, but why 'createState()' method in TestChildWidget not called?

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: new TestPage()
    );
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget{
  TestPageState createState(){
    print('TestPageState createState');

    return new TestPageState();
  }
}
class TestPageState extends State<TestPage>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('TestPageState Build');

      // TODO: implement build
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new TestChildWidget(),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("刷新"),
            onPressed: () => setState(() => print('setState')), //build method will called, new TestChildWidget() will be called
          )
        ],
      );
  }
}

class TestChildWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  TestChildWidget(){
     //new TestChildWidget(), this default construtor will be called, but why createState() not called?
  }
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    print('TestChildWidget createState');

    return new TestChildWidgetState();
  }

}

class TestChildWidgetState extends State<TestChildWidget>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('TestChildWidgetState build');

    // TODO: implement build
    return Text('1111');
  }
}
```

in the 'TestPageState', I put a button to call 'setState' method. new TestChildWidget() will create a new  TestChildWidget,default construtor TestChildWidget() is called, but why 'createState()' method in TestChildWidget not called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when setState() called, it will call

```
abstract class Widget extends DiagnosticableTree {
  const Widget({ this.key });
  final Key key;
  ···
  static bool canUpdate(Widget oldWidget, Widget newWidget) {
    return oldWidget.runtimeType == newWidget.runtimeType
        && oldWidget.key == newWidget.key;
  }
}
```

if canUpdate() return true, it means there is no need to create a new element.

Answer (score 0):

It creates a state or calls the state `build` when the state is created.

```
class TestChildWidgetState extends State<TestChildWidget>{
  TestChildWidgetState(){
    print("Created only once");
  }
}
```

The framework calls createState whenever it inflates a StatefulWidget, which means that multiple State objects might be associated with the same StatefulWidget if that widget has been inserted into the tree in multiple places. Similarly, if a StatefulWidget is removed from the tree and later inserted in to the tree again, the framework will call createState again to create a fresh State object, simplifying the lifecycle of State objects.
See [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)

Comment: why, new TestChildWidget() create a new widget, why createState() not called?

Comment: `StatefulWidget` must retain the state.

Comment: does it mean 'new TestChildWidget()', widget tree does not remove this child widget and readd?

Answer (score 0):

*print(...)* log maybe not print to console but Flutter have called *createState()*

You can try use:

```
developer.debugger(when: true);
```

in *createState()*

Answer (score 0):

The Stateful widget has a default parameter 'Key'. If you supply it with a different value each time - that would enforce new state to be created i.e createState() called.
Instead of new TestChildWidget(), try:

```
new TestChildWidget(
   key: Key('different key for diff states'),  // or key: UniqueKey()
),
```

I actually use the same key value for states that are same, in order to have the caching in those cases.